# Will you halte zu mir?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, language

> Part number one?  I'll never Tell,
>   but when you figure it out, drop the last L
>
> Part two is straightforward, though a little crass:
>   give the plural form of what comes out your ...
>
> The third and final part, you'll see
>   can be found by thinking empirically

What word am I describing?

**Edit** -- no guesses after 20 hours, so here's a hint:

Hint #1

> I said I'll never Tell, though I'll gladly open a few more Gates

Comment: Is the fourth line "..." supposed to be "ass", or was it intentionally styled as such?

Comment: If I were to tell you, part two would be more than a *little* crass.  There's a rhyme scheme for a reason

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word is:

> BILDUNGSROMAN
> William Tell -> Will -> Wil + dungs (plural form) + roman (empire)
> The term Bildungsroman comes from German, and refers to a work (novel, etc.) which tells a coming of age story. The German words in the title (halte zu mir) translate to "stand by me", which is the title of a Rob Reiner-directed coming of age film.

Comment: Nice puzzle, by the way. Enjoyable to work on.

Comment: Nice answer!  Want to take a crack at the relevance of the title?

Comment: I added text to my answer.